# wp_list_pages Title attribute and Order

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I found a post on this site to add a custom "mytheme_list_pages" to the functions.php file in order to add the title attribute to a link. While this works to add the title attribute to the "href" output, it no longer preserves the order of the menu as wp_list_pages does. Can someone tell me how to order the output of the custom code below?

I'm calling the function from my page.php file like this:

```
<?php mytheme_list_pages('exclude=819&title_li='); ?>
```

The custom function below:

```
<?php 
function mytheme_list_pages($param) {
  $pages = get_pages($param); 
  foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $li  = '<li><a href="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '" title="';
    $li .= esc_attr($page->post_title);
    $li .= '">';
    $li .= $page->post_title;
    $li .= '</a></li>';
    echo $li;
  }
}
?>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Robert, it's in your $param variable.  Can you please edit your question to include the contents of $param when you call this function?

Comment: Thanks, Cale. Actually, the exclusions do work. Just wanting to have this custom function order the page output as I've ordered the pages in Wordpress. @cale_b

Comment: I actually found it by adding "&sort_column=menu_order" to my params. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated code,

```
    <?php mytheme_list_pages('exclude=819&title_li=&sort_column=menu_order'); ?>

<?php 
function mytheme_list_pages($param) {
  $pages = get_pages($param); 
  foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $li  = '<li><a href="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '" title="';
    $li .= esc_attr($page->post_title);
    $li .= '">';
    $li .= $page->post_title;
    $li .= '</a></li>';
    echo $li;
  }
}
?>
```

for more information http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages